# Cross Platform Desktop Application like Steam - What technologies are available

Tags: java, c++, swing, qt, javafx

I am looking to develop a cross platform desktop application (along the lines of steam), I currently have good working knowledge of Java.

My question is what is the best way to create this program?

I have done alot of research into this topic but I am still unsure of which technology to use, I have researched Qt, JavaFX, Swing and C++.

As my research has found all Steam is fundamentally is a web browser that just renders HTML pages.

As my expertise are Java I am influenced to use JavaFX / Swing but I am concerned that the GUI's are not up to scratch using these frameworks.

Qt has also come up alot in my research and looks like a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

I researched this quite a bit and was at this cross-roads several months ago.  In my opinion, Qt is the way to go.  You can develop cross-platform C++ apps with a traditional GUI look and feel as well as use QML (Qt-Meta-Language) to develop UIs  with more of a fluid-like touch interface.  My codes run cross-platform on OSX, Linux, and Windows.  In each case I get native look and feel with the UIs

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I was thinking of writing the application using Qt, Qt being the application itself which hold a web view, obviously the web view will hold the HTML / CSS / JavaScript and will be solely used for the front end. Do you think this is a good way about it or should I just use pure Qt?

Comment: I have not tried your particular flavor of coding but you might check out this Qt 5 demo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhWS_bN-T3k, its a fair amount of marketing hype but maybe you can spot some examples of what you are after in the demo.